# Interfacing C and Python using swig

Tags: python, c, executable, swig, binaryfiles

Using the Tutorials available online: http://www.swig.org/papers/PyTutorial98/PyTutorial98.pdf

I am trying to re-use the available examples already but I am running into the below error:

> swig: cannot execute binary file

example.c

```
/* example.c */
double Foo = 7.5;
int fact(int n) {
if (n <= 1) return 1;
else return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

example.i

```
// example.i
%module example
%{
#include "headers.h"
%}
int fact(int n);
double Foo;
#define SPAM 42
```

Error:

```
$swig -python example.i
swig: cannot execute binary file
```

Any pointers? How could I overcome this error inorder to generate example_wrap.c file?

```
chmod +x example.i
$file example.i
example.i: ASCII C++ program text
```

Comment: I think the error is about _swig_ and not _example.i_. Did you try `which swig` then `ls -al` (to check the exec permission) and `file` on the output? Try running `swig --help`, or run it by its full path.

Comment: I do have the exec permissions.
file swig returns: swig: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, SPARC, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped.
$swig --help
-bash: /auto/ses/bin/swig: cannot execute binary file

Comment: The output indicates your `swig` binary is built for a 32-bit SPARC system.  If you're not running on a 32-bit SPARC, you'll need a more appropriate swig binary.

Comment: A note: it should also works on 64bit _SPARC_. But I doubt that you're running on a _Solaris SPARC_. You're probably running on an _Intel_ (_x86_ or _x64_) architecture (don't know the _Ux_ / _Linux_ flavor), and that's the _swig_ that you should have/run. BTW: how did you install _swig_? And what OS are you on (`uname -a`)?

Answer (score 0):

You're following a tutorial from 1998 and you try to execute a binary for sparc processors. Something's seriously vintage, here. You are probably trying to recreate things from an archive where someone tried to document what he did >15 years ago.

Do yourself a favour and use current versions of swig and python, and learn from current documentation http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python. Swig has seen major improvements and python has seen major changes in the meantime. c was already perfect back then :-). If you have C code from then that you want to use from python, use current versions swig and python and it will work.